# Two column problem

Tags: two-column, minipage, parcolumns

I'm trying to replicate a certain part of a scanned book.

However, I'm unable to get two columns, which have enumeratation on the left, 
line of the right column which is in the parallel with first (part of sentence or a) line of the left part, and are without indentation.
I tried with ''parcolumns'', aligning was good, but I was unable to get enumerate to work, also the biggest problem was to turn **off** indentation.
I could *fake* enumeration, but it would be good if I don't have to. **;)** I made screenshot.

I'm grateful for any help.

[a busy cat](![a busy cat http://i.minus.com/iz5pLRLxpz2cO.png](http://i.minus.com/iz5pLRLxpz2cO.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: each item is split into its two components. The `enumitem` package is optional, but with it it's easier to customize enumerated lists. With the `ragged2e` package text set ragged right can be hyphenated using `\RaggedRight` instead of the usual `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example text

\newcommand{\phrase}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1em\relax}{\RaggedRight#1\par\kern-\prevdepth}%
  \hspace{2em}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\reference}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1em\relax}{\RaggedRight#1\par\kern-\prevdepth}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
\item\phrase{Könnten Sie uns genauer schildern, wie der Unfall passiert ist?}
     \reference{Höflichkeit (Vgl. S. 97)}

\item\phrase{Hätte der Autofahrer doch nicht überholt!}
     \reference{Wunschätze (Vgl. S. 97ff.)}

\item\phrase{Wenn der entgegenkommende Fahrer das Lenkrad nicht in letzter
             Sekunde herumgerissen hätte, wären beide Autos frontal
             zusammengestoßen}
     \reference{Konditionalsätze (Vgl. S. 99ff.)}
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg, this seems to be what I'm looking for. ;)

Answer (score 7):

To avoid entering the numbers by hand (as in Mico's answer) you could write as follows (but the solution is clearly less elegant than egreg's):[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{konj}
    \setcounter{konj}{1}
\newcommand{\Konj}[2]{%
    \smallskip(\thekonj)\stepcounter{konj}
    &#1
    &#2
    }

{\RaggedRight
\begin{tabular}{%
    @{}l@{\hspace{1.5em}}%          Dimensions of col 1 and space btw cols 1&2
    p{.5\textwidth}@{\hspace{1.5em}}%   Dimensions of col 2 and space btw cols 2&3
    p{.4\textwidth}@{}%                 Dimension of col 3
    }
\Konj{K\"onnten Sie die Bratw\"urste bitte etwas l\"anger kochen?}{H\"oflichkeit}\\
\Konj{W\"aren die Bratw\"urste nur etwas l\"anger gekocht worden!}{Wunschs\"atze}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please correct your MWE. There are extraneous attempts to escape the brackets `\[` and extraneous `[` also.

Comment: @DanielHarbour -- this might still be improved by use of `ragged2e` and `\RaggedRight`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I didn’t know about that.  Addition made.  Peter Grill: Thanks for picking up on the brackets.  I don’t know how they got in there.  I’ve also taken the opportunity to correct the German in one place and to break up the specification of column dimensions over three lines so they’re easier to customize.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your setup and objectives correctly, you may be better off using a tabular environment, such as a [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment. The following is an MWE that illustrates how this may be done. (Note: I've updated the code to incorporate Herbert's helpful comments.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document} 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l XX @{}}
\toprule
(1) & Könnten Sie uns genauer schildern, wie der Unfall passiert ist?
& Höf"|lichkeit (Vgl. S.~97)\\ % break up f-l ligature
(2) & Hätte der Autofahrer doch nicht überholt!
& Wunschsätze (Vgl. S.~97ff.)\\
(3) & Wenn der entgegenkommende Fahrer das Lenkrad nicht
in letzter Sekunde herumgerissen hätte, wären beide Autos
frontal zusammengestoßen.
& Konditionalsätze (Vgl. S. 99ff.)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this [1803 dictionary](http://books.google.it/books?id=UORJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA315&lpg=PA315&dq=Höflichkeit&source=bl&ots=1xgJ7kY3aN&sig=9mEC5v4ivQ4puIT0VYPySS-TOyQ&hl=it&sa=X&ei=zFpoUMroGYjNsgbO4IDQCw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Höflichkeit&f=false) there seems to be a ligature in "Höflichkeit". I also learnt the meaning in Italian. `:)`

Comment: @egreg - Wow, that's quite a find!! I love it!! (Höflichkeit is cortesia in Italian, right?) However, when *not* using Blackletter fonts -- as is the case, say, in the text excerpt posted by the OP... -- I understand that current best practice in German typography is *not* to use an f-l ligature across a morpheme boundary. I may be mistaken, though... :-)

Comment: Maybe. I still don't understand *why* it shouldn't be used here: "lich" is a suffix. It's not a composite word like "Auflage".

Comment: @egreg - My understanding is that (in German at least) ligatures should be suppressed not only when two "independent" words are combined (e.g., Tieflager and Schöpflöffel) but also when one combines (a) a prefix and a main word (as in your example, Auflage) and (b) a main word and a suffix (e.g., höflich, hilflos, schweflig); an *exception* for case (b) is made for the f-i ligature (e.g., streifig, affig). See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/rmligs for more on this.

Comment: I'd like to see an authoritative source.

Comment: @Mico I'd say that _schweflig_, however is a case like _zweifle_, i.e. the _l_ actually belongs to the base morpheme {schwef(e)l}.

Comment: @egreg -- For an "authoritative" source, how about p. 69, *Duden*, Vol. 1, Mannheim, 1996 ("Richtlinien für den Schriftsatz").

Comment: @doncherry - Are kopflos and Zöpflein less controversial candidates for avoidance of the f-l ligature? :-)

Comment: @Mico Yup :) [filler]

Comment: @Mico: Thank you for your effort. I tried something like this, it seemed hackish-not elegant solution, also it's a bit manual.

Comment: @Mico: you are using `ragged2e`, the reason why you do not need the `\arraybackslash`. And, of course, redefing the tabularx column in this case makes sense: `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}}`

Comment: ligatures should not go over morphems. No ligature in "höflich" or "auffällig". An exception is the case that a following syllable starts with an "i", like "ich", "isch" aso. "süffig" has a ffi ligature but "trefflich" only a ff ligature.

Comment: @Herbert - many thanks for the very helpful tabularx-related comments (and for the comments on ligature suppression too, of course). I'll update my answer to incorporate your comments.

Comment: To avoid wrong ligatures in German you could use rmligs (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/rmligs). It helps a lot.

Comment: @schmendrich -- thanks for this suggestion. In fact, I mention the `rmligs` package in one of the comments to egreg above.

Comment: Oh, didn't see you suggested it too. But "better safe than sorry" or "doppelt hält besser" (German) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

as an own environment, allows a pagebreak after each entry if you use the package `ltablex` instead of `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lining]{libertine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\newcounter{LstCnt}
\newenvironment{Liste}
  {\setcounter{LstCnt}{0}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}\par\noindent%
   \tabularx{\textwidth}{@{\stepcounter{LstCnt}(\arabic{LstCnt})\kern\tabcolsep}Xl@{}}\toprule}
  {\endtabularx\par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\heavyrulewidth}\par}

\begin{document} 

\begin{Liste}
Könnten Sie uns genauer schildern, wie der Unfall passiert ist?
  & Höf"|lichkeit (Vgl. S.~\pageref{foo})\\ 

Hätte der Autofahrer doch nicht überholt!
  & Wunschsätze (Vgl. S.~\pageref{bar})\\     
Wenn der entgegenkommende Fahrer das Lenkrad nicht in letzter Sekunde 
herumgerissen hätte, wären beide Autos frontal zusammengestoßen.
  & Konditionalsätze (Vgl. S.~\pageref{baz})
\end{Liste}

\newpage\null\label{foo}\newpage\null\label{bar}\newpage\null\label{baz}% only for demo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Herbert, but is it possible to have (sometimes) just right column (or left)?

Comment: sure, you can use column specifier `r` instead of `l` for the right column or `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}` for the `X` column. For single tabular cells use `\RaggedLeft`, if needed.